# How to prepare your training data input when your data input frequency is different from data output frequency

Tags: python, r, pandas, time-series, forecasting

Given daily data points and you are asked to always take until the 5th of the month data points to predict the current month and the next 2 month price.

As of now, I only can think of aggregating the Jan and 1-5th Feb data points together as Jan monthly price, then use that as monthly input to forecast Feb, Mar and Apr monthly price. But I don't find this method is fair because now the Jan 20 monthly data has more data points which is different from Jan 19 or Jan 18 input.

Monthly price = Average of the daily price on the particular month

How would you suggest to prepare the data set fairly to train your machine learning model for monthly price forecast?

[image]